# VUE Js V-IF toggle not working as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Let me write code first

```
<div class="block" data-toggle="tooltip" title="click to change the name of this button, and its actions" v-for="(button, button_index) in menus" @click="open_button_details(button_index)">
     <div v-if="button.showPicker"  @click="showPicker($event, button_index)">'hello'
     </div>
  </div>
```

I have an array of data object with multiple buttons with showPicker attribute as :

```
menus:
    [
    {
      "name": "Menu item 1",
      "trigger_type": null,
      "trigger_value": null,
                "remainingCount" : 30,
                "maxCount" : 30,
                "message": '',
                "hasError": false,
                "showPicker" : false
    },
    {
      "name": "Menu item 2",
      "trigger_type": null,
      "trigger_value": null,
```

Show Picker Method

```
showPicker : function(event, button_index){
        var _this = this.menus[button_index];
        _this.showPicker = !_this.showPicker;
    }
```

Now v-if works only once. It show the 'Hello text' when `showPicker` is true. But when toggled `showPicker` to false it doesn't go away. Could you please let me know what went wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Any errors in the console?  Also, to make things easier, maybe just pass `button` itself (instead of `button_index`) to the event handler and then you can flip the `showPicker` flag directly vs looking it up inside the array.

Comment: it goes away for me. (this is just a good practice :: -- include :key when you use v-for)

Comment: :key solved the issue thank you @divine .. looks like there's no way i can select your answer as correct.

Comment: @Geniusintrouble no problem. i would recommend using VSCODE and installing Vuejs plugin called VETUR. it will highlight few errors while coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to divine, the solution is using `:key` with `v-for`. 
Looks like without `:key` the `v-for` doesn't work as expected at times.